# How can I display mail composer in landscape mode by using MFMailComposeViewController in cocos2d?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am writing a game in cocos2d. I want to add MFMailComposeViewController to the scene. 
So, when I touch a CcLabel in the scene the mail sheet is opened.

```
@interface EmailScene : CCScene <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker;
}

-(void)displayComposerSheet;

@end

@implementation EmailScene

- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        [self displayComposerSheet];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"srikanth.rongali786@gmail.com"]; 
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:picker.view];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    CCScene *Scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer *Layer = [GameWinScreen node];
    [Scene addChild:Layer];

    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:Scene];
}

@end
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4a77b9ceb9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4a77b9ceb9.png)

But, the problem is my game is in landscape mode. So, I need the mail sheet to display in landscape mode. But, here the mail sheet is displayed in portrait mode. And the keyboard is appearing in landscape mode. But, the mail composure sheet is in  portrait  mode.

And how can we change the "sent from my iPhone" to "Sent From My iPad"

Thank you.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3eb39ea1de.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3eb39ea1de.png)

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in Apple's implementation.  Have you verified that it is in the wrong orientation on the device itself?

Comment: i have also the problem..i am using cocos2d 99.5......sp...start a bounty...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to manually rotate view...:

```
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));

[picker.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
```

Comment: if i rotate the picker it works well...but when i close the picker.view......by pressing close button......my original scene transformed to Portrait mode......

Comment: uh.... try to add same two lines before (or after, i'm not sure, try what is the best for you) [picker.view removeFromSuperview]; but with degreesToRadian(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own mailcomposer that is derived from MFMailComposeViewController and you can overwrite only the function  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceorientation.
I didn't try this, just give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Who is managing your EmailScene object? If you have followed the MVC pattern, try present the MFMailComposeViewController object using the viewController of EmailScene view. This will work provided you have supported all orientations in the view controller.

Use:

```
-(void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Instead of adding the MFMailComposeViewController's view as a subview.

Edit: Try to present the MFMailComposeViewController using the root view controller.